# Processing input before giving input to parser

Tags: parsing, stanford-nlp

What kind of processing should be done to the input which is given to the parser.

As of know i am using stanford parser.jar but there is also stanford coreNLP.jar what is the difference between parser.jar and coreNLP.jar parsing method

As per coreNLP documentation you can pass the operation you want to do as input in the annotators

***COMMAND:***

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref -file input.txt
```

To use parsing in coreNLP can i pass only parse or should I pass all the annotators  except dcoref

***i.e.)***

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,parse -file input.txt
                                      or
java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref -file input.txt
```

Does the parser.jar has sentence splitting in built in it's jar

Can I give paragraph as input and get sentence and their parsed data as out

or should i give only one sentence at a time
Thank you,

Comment: its not a silly questions. stanford area is not explored a lot all question related to this is valid. Please remove the first sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CoreNLP annotators can be thought of as a dependency graph. The parser annotator depends on tokenization (`tokenize`) and sentence splitting (`ssplit`) only. So, you could run the parser with your first command:

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,parse -file input.txt
```

If you know your text is pre-tokenized, the easiest thing to do is to set the options `tokenize.whitespace = "true"` in your properties file (or pass it in as a flag: `-tokenize.whitespace`). To only sentence split at the end of a line, you can set the option (`ssplit.eolonly`).

But, by default, yes CoreNLP will tokenize and split up your sentence for you. You can just feed in a pile of text, and it will output parsed sentences.

Comment: so why is there difference between CoreNLP  and parser output  which should i use .Which will give better results

Comment: The CoreNLP `parse` annotator and the Stanford parser are exactly the same. There should not be a difference between the outputs, beyond that CoreNLP does other things too.

Comment: but as per this link [link](http://rants.tempura.org/2013/03/12/stanford-core-nlp-parsing.html) it gives different result between coreNLP and parser when used with POS in coreNLP

Comment: This is only if you have the `pos` annotator enabled, and even then the difference is likely to be rare and small. It's unlikely to make a big difference in any downstream task.

Comment: So there is no it doesn't matter if i use parser or coreNLP with POS enabled  both are almost the same. Nothing is better or worse then the other thing right